# Seeing if rotation has chaned with if statement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, if-statement

I am trying to see if my prefabs has chanced rotation in anyway
but this ain't working any one know how i have to do this
I am calling this script in other script and that's working the Debug.Log Shows up

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Pawn : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject pawnName;

    public Transform tf;


    [SerializeField]
    float eulerAngX;
    [SerializeField]
    float eulerAngY;
    [SerializeField]
    float eulerAngZ;



    public void Start()
    {
        tf = GetComponent<Transform>();
    }

    public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        
    }

    public void PawnHasFallen()
    {
        eulerAngX = transform.localEulerAngles.x;
        eulerAngY = transform.localEulerAngles.y;
        eulerAngZ = transform.localEulerAngles.z;
        Debug.Log("Calling this script");

        if (eulerAngX < 0 || eulerAngX > 0 || eulerAngY < 0 && eulerAngY > 0 || eulerAngZ > 0 || eulerAngZ < 0)
        {
            Debug.Log(pawnName + "Has Fallen");
        }
       
    }

}
```

Comment: what does `not working` mean exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general note that due to floating point precision general checks for exact equality might fail and you should rather either use a certain threshold or [`Mathf.Approximately`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Approximately.html).

So instead of

```
eulerAngX < 0 || eulerAngX > 0
```

you might rather want to use

```
!Mathf.Approximately(eulerAngX, 0)
```

or even simplier in order to check if any of them is not `0` at once

```
if(!Mathf.Approximately(transform.localEulerAngles.sqrMagnitude, 0))
```

---

Note though that for a pawn which can be rotated around Y without fall it is way simplier to check if it's UP vector is still pointing UP ;)

```
if(!Mathf.Approximately(Vector3.Angle(Vector3.up, transfom.up), 0f))
{
    Debug.Log($"{name} has Fallen", this);
}
```

Comment: its working if i put it in the start command but it aint working if i call it trough a another script

Comment: @BenjaminVenema again: what does `not working` mean exactly?

Comment: the if statements isn't working its only working if I call the function in the void start. But It does call out de debug.log